# Prove that there exists a set of $k$ edge-disjoint walks that cover a graph with $2k$ odd-degree vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I need some help understanding this proof.

Full question:

For some $k$, let $G$ be a connected graph with $2k$ odd-degree vertices, and any number of even-degree vertices. We say that a set of edge-disjoint walks cover $G$ if no edge is repeated within a walk, and every edge of $G$ is used in exactly one walk in the set.Prove that there exists a set of k edge-disjoint walks that cover $G$. (Hint: Turn this into an Eulerian circuit problem by adding $k$ new vertices and $2k$ new edges.

Full answer:

[image]

The part that I don't understand are the (capital) $W$s. Where did they come from? Why are there $k$ of them? Why are they between the pairs of the newly formed edges?

I understand that a Eulerian circuit must exist since all the vertices are now even-degree, but I don't understand how we break it up into $k$ walks, and why we position them the way we do.

Comment: You removed $k$ parts of a cycle. $k$ paths remain and they are the $W_i$.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk Umm I'm not confused about why they remain after we remove the other parts. I'm confused about how/why they exist in the first place. We're asked to prove that there are k walks. Why can we just "assume" that the walk contains W1...Wk, and then use it for our result.

Comment: It's like "prove that there is an elephant in the room." "Okay, so assume this room contains an elephant, QED," you know?

Comment: You added stuff to the graph, the result is a walk covering all edges. Then you remove exactly the stuff you added and conclude that the original graph must have had $k$ edge-disjoint walks. There is no assumption of the type you fear.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk But why are there k walks? How do we know it's not just 1 big walk at the beginning for example?

Comment: Then there could be at most 2 odd-degree vertices. So this would be possible for $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If we remove one of the additional vertices from $G'$, the resulting graph contains an Eulerian walk $W_1$ since there are now two vertices of odd degree. Removing the next additional vertex splits $W_1$ into two walks, let's call them $W_1, W_2$. Removing the next vertex splits one of the walks $W_1, W_2$ into two walks again resulting in walks $W_1, W_2, W_3$. Repeat until all additional vertices have been removed, count the walks produced.

Since an Eulerian walk visits every edge exactly once, splitting it into several parts results in edge disjoint walks and because we only removed the additional edges and vertices, the resulting walks cover $G$.

Comment: Why does removing the next additional vertex split $W_1$ into two walks?