# prove that the minimum number of trails in an odd graph is n/2

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

In my HW assignments I was asked to prove that
If a graph G consists of only odd degree vertices, then the minimum number of trails that decompose it (without having any common edge between each two trails) is n/2.

I saw a prove for a similar claim that goes for a 2k number of odd vertices. obviously since every graph contains an even number of degrees, then the number of vertices is even so that goes for proving there exist n/2 paths in the graph G , the only thing that is missing for me is to understand why is this the minimum number of trails.

The prove of the other claim is here: 
[Prove that there exists a set of $k$ edge-disjoint walks that cover a graph with $2k$ odd-degree vertices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577622/prove-that-there-exists-a-set-of-k-edge-disjoint-walks-that-cover-a-graph-with)

I thank in advance to any one who answers:)

Comment: What does the quantity $n$ represent?

Comment: number of vertices in the graph

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $n$ is the order of $G$, then $n$ must be even by the Handshake Lemma. If you add a vertex $v$ and then connect it to all the vertices in $G$, you will create an Eulerian graph $G+v$. If you start the Eulerian circuit at $v$, then you must go to some vertex in $G$ and travel along a trail in $G$ and return to $v$. You will do this $n/2$ times, each time choosing a different edge disjoint trail in $G$. Then delete $v$ and you will have your desired decomposition of $G$.

Comment: I just dont understand why this has to be the minimal number of trails.

Comment: In order to get fewer trails, some of the trails generated would have to be merged. They would have to have at least one vertex in common and it would have to be an end vertex too. What would that do to the Eulerian circuit in $G+v$?